# CVXPY convex but getting DCP error for constraint y^2/x + z <= 1

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4652619/632365) on Mathematics SE</sub>

---

I have a convex objective function and a convex constraint of the form $y^2/x + z \leq 1$ on the domain $x \geq 0$. But I'm not sure how to encode this constraint in a way that cvxpy will accept it. It seems to be rejecting it because it can't convince itself that the constraint is convex.

Here is a simple example code

```py
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

n = 5
x = cp.Variable(n)

xtarget = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
A = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n, n])
B = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n, n])
y = A @ x
z = B @ x
obj = cp.sum_squares(xtarget - x)
constraints = [x>= 0, y ** 2 / x + z <= 1]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints)
prob.solve()
```

This gives the error:

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The following constraints are not DCP
```

I have tried to replace `y ** 2 / x + z <= 1` with `cp.multiply(y ** 2, cp.pos_inv(x)) + z <= 1` so that it know that $x$ variable is non-negative. It still gives me the DCP error.

Is there a way to reformulate the problem such that it satisfies the DCP rules?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $y^2/x$ is parsed element wise operation here. Yes to second comment. $z \leq 1$ should be implied right? I don’t think I need to add that.

Comment: Thanks @RodrigodeAzevedo I made a post in math stack exchange. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4652619/632365

Answer (score 0):

You should use the cvxpy function `quad_over_lin(y,x)` to express y^2/x.